# Defining a differentiable curve's torsion

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

In exercise 10, page 26 of Manfredo's Differentiable Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, we are asked to look at the following differentiable curve:
$$\alpha(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} (t,0,e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}) &, \mbox{if}\, t>0 \\
(t,e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}},0)&, \mbox{if}\, t<0\\
(0,0,0) &, \mbox{if}\, t=0
 \end{array} \right.$$
The d part of this question asks

> Show that τ can be defined so that τ ≡ 0, even though α is not a
> plane curve.

I have calculated the binormal vector to be $b(t)=(0,1,0)$ for $t>0$ and $(0,0,1)$ for $t<0$, and in both these cases the torsion $\tau=1$. What might he mean when saying that it can defined to be zero?

Comment: You’re wrong about $\tau$. If $b$ is constant, then what is $\tau$?

Comment: of course, thank you. As the definitions are still new to me sometimes I flip them up without even realizing it